# How to convert an integer to std::u16string (C++11)?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, casting

There is no method `std::to_u16string(...)`. Obviously `static_cast` doesn't seem the most appropiate way to make such conversion.

For the opposite conversion, from `string` to `int`, a converter may be defined using the function `std::stoi()`, but from `int` to `u16string` it's not working.

I tried the following:

```
int i = 1234;
std::u16string s;

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
s = convert.from_bytes(std::to_string(i));

std::cout << s.str() << "  (" << s.length() << ")" << std::endl;
```

I also tried to do this:

```
typedef std::basic_stringstream<char16_t> u16ss;
u16ss ss;
ss << 1234;
std::u16string s = ss.str();
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to carry out this conversion directly, or there must be some intermediate conversions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
std::u16string to_u16string(int const &i) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>, char16_t> conv;
  return conv.from_bytes(std::to_string(i));
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cca4d983a00bc6d5)

Comment: Note that this defaults to big-endian byte ordering. If you want little-endian try `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>`.

Comment: @user2093113 thanx, adopted.

Comment: @101010 Thanks, that was it. I wasn't using `little_endian` and that was why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

> Standard library header  (C++11)(deprecated in C++17)(removed
> in C++26)
> [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/codecvt)

You can use std::filesystem::path

```
std::u16string to_u16string(const std::filesystem::path& str) {
    return str.u16string();
}
std::u16string to_u16string(int i) {    
    return to_u16string(std::to_string(i));
}
```